# Apache processing my PHP file but showing "?>" at the start

Tags: php, apache

I have a problem regarding my Apache Server running in my local machine. Until yesterday everything was fine, but today it won't proccess my .php files correctly: when the pages are displayed they all show the ending bracket of php, screwing all of my client based application. 
Here's one .php file example. They all suffer the same problem now.

```
<?php
/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';


// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

$unidad = $_GET['unidad'];
// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT a.unidad, a.tpo_med, a.num_med, a.consumo, a.fec_med, a.est_med, b.razon FROM gmest_med a, gcunidad b WHERE a.unidad='$unidad' AND a.unidad=b.unidad ORDER BY fec_med DESC LIMIT 0,1") or die(mysql_error());



// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["medidor"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();
        $product["unidad"] = $row["unidad"];
        $product["tpo_med"] = $row["tpo_med"];
        $product["num_med"] = $row["num_med"];
        $product["fec_med"] = $row["fec_med"];


$product["est_med"] = $row["est_med"];
    $product["consumo"] = $row["consumo"];
    $product["razon"] = $row["razon"];

    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["medidor"], $product);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

This will display the following JSON (for example):

```
?>{"medidor":[{"unidad":"410020","tpo_med":"ACT1","num_med":"A06S831658","fec_med":"2015-10-13 00:00:00","est_med":"3309","consumo":"31","razon":"ARIAS, HUMBERTO C"}],"success":1}
```

Comment: Not sure what the reason could be, but you can safely remove ending '?>'

Comment: What does db_connect.php look like? Make sure to mask password info before posting.

Comment: db_donnect.php just connects to my MySQL server using mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error()).
Also, i tried removing the final bracket '?>' from the code. It still shows it like I posted above

Comment: So remove `db_connect` and try to echo simple array.

Comment: One of your included files ends with two `?>`. Check db_connect.php and any php files that it includes. If it is not in there, check the ini value of `auto_prepend_file` to make sure it isn't automatically including a php file for you.

Comment: Thanks Josh J. Silly me, I forgot to check all of my included files. Turns out the error was on one of these!

Comment: dbconnect.php has an extra ?> or some file has an extra... try searching using the following regex `/\?\>\n\?\>/g/`